# Installing Progress Bars

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

More specifically from this site: https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress

I've connected the provided .js and .css files to my main html file, but the next step tells me to "Simply call start() and done() to control the progress bar."

```
NProgress.start();
NProgress.done();
```

I'm still new to javascript, in which file do I place the above coding? And do I need to specify anything in between those parenthesis?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In your own JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it in your Javascript file.

It is mainly usefull if you want do an AJAX request for example, because it can take a long time compare to simple Javascript instructions with no HTTP request.

With an AJAX call with jQuery you can for example do this :

```
//The request begin
NProgress.start();

$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
}).done(function() {
  //The request is done
   NProgress.done();
});
```